# How to get links in comments from the YouTube api following the move to Google+ comments

Tags: youtube-api, google-plus, youtube-data-api

In the new YouTube Google + comments system how can I retrieve comments that contain links.

For example if someone posts a link to another youtube video as follows:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZNHuFjnmUo

This gets converted to a link by the google plus system. The title of the video is shown as the text rather that the url. i.e. The html shown within the comments is this:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZNHuFjnmUo" class="ot-anchor" rel="nofollow">Francis HATES Google+</a>
```

However the api for that comment only returns the title of the video which is pretty useless seeing as I want to get the link too. I am guessing that the system converts the url into an <a> tag which is stored in the database but then the api strips out the html when its requested so it only returns the videos title.

I have posted a defect here:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5500

But that bug list seems to have very little activity going on in terms of responses to issues.

So is there another way to get the data I need?

Comment: Looks like this was resolved:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5500

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't. Or if it has it hasn't been set live yet. It isn't clear to me what "fixed" means in the context of that bug tracker. I have tested it and it still doesn't give the link.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do while this bug remains is to extract the comment id and use it in the Google+ API with an [`activities.get`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/get) request. This will return the full post with all links.

A bit cumbersome since it needs one request for each comment you want to check, but it seems to be the only way while the bug remains.

To take an example from the video you linked in the issue:
This YouTube comment returned by the API includes a YouTube link:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/rgkDKeSc-1o
       /comments/z12hvvcgxznkufyo304ci1iqlnandzxjpes
```

You can use the `z...` ID in a request to the Google+ API:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.get?activityId=z12hvvcgxznkufyo304ci1iqlnandzxjpes

Which includes the full post including links.